# Visual Studio 2010 Multi Project Solution Add class

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm a rookie to this sort of thing so please bear with me.  I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that is made up of 4 different projects (Windows app).

All of the dependencies are set up so they compile in the proper order when you build.

I just added a new class to one of the projects.  I need to access this class from one of the other projects, but for some reason my new class is invisible to the other projects within the solution.  All of the other classes in the project are visible to other projects.  My new class is the only one that is not.

When you add a new class in a scenario such as mine, is there something else you need to do other than add the file with the class and then click build?

Comment: the class is public, but how do i reload the reference?

Comment: What language? C++, C#, VB?

Comment: The main project is VB and the other 3 are C#

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

It seems as if the secondary projects were set to go to "Release" and they were compiling to "Release", but my Main Project was looking for them in "Debug"

Comment: It sounds like your projects are referencing each other by dll and not via project reference. This is going to be very hard to maintain.  You should use project references.

Comment: I didn't know this existed.  I will check into this.

Comment: Question is, how do I change them.  When I go into project properties, it gives me the option to add reference.  I select the project from the project list, but it appears in the reference list as a dll.

Comment: It should appear as a dll reference, that's what it is.  But by defining the reference by the project instead of by browsing to a dll if the referenced dll changes directory because of a build change (debug vs release) the dependent project will know where to get that dll.